# How can I clear an iPad from another company's DEP?

Tags: ipad, automated-device-enrollment, mdm

The company I work for is in the process of enrolling all iPads into MDM and correcting devices not in the DEP.

We've found one that we've had for a while. It's in another DEP **but not** in another MDM... So we are prevented from adding it our DEP but we have nobody to contact about correcting it. We contacted Apple with no results. Nobody has a serialized proof of purchase, the device wasn't asset tagged properly whenever it was acquired.

My best guess was that somebody independently bought a refurb unit from a third party seller.

How can I go about properly cataloging this into our DEP?

Comment: Curious how you know you own it without receipts. “Trust us, we don’t have records of purchases from a year or two back.” isn't usually a strong opening point to get Apple to reconsider their policy, but +1 for asking. These things can and will happen given the volume of hardware that ships. One point I'm stumped about - How do you know it’s DEP?

Comment: @bmike that's a fair question and I suppose I don't **"Know"** with a capital-K. I can only say that this is a multi-billion dollar company with a fleet of hundreds of iPads and I don't think an employee would steal one and add it to corporate inventory. I'm surprised that we only found *one* in this situation.

Comment: Bummer not knowing. Apple likely won’t budge on disclosing who purchased any serial number so all you can do is ask them politely to research in case a mistake was made and hope they can fix it or connect the dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The organization that owns the device is normally the only entity that can release it. You can watch the traffic without impacting it but not really get around the enrollment process without a solid jailbreak and some network skills.

- [Can iPad SSL/TLS traffic be inspected during DEP enrollment?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220707/can-ipad-ssl-tls-traffic-be-inspected-during-dep-enrollment)

I would start with [network packet capture / tracing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace) to confirm which entity has convinced Apple to exert DEP control by logging DNS lookups or packet capture and not even pester Apple if you can't document your request in specific detail.

If there is a clear mistake, the other third party will they will likely want to help you out or at least learn more about this hardware.

- you either will be reporting a stolen device to them or they will learn they messed up releasing that device.
- It’s also remotely possible there was a serial number mixup and they can contact Apple with you to fix that.

Some day they could need someone else’s help and they wouldn’t want to manage your machine or be liable for infringing on your rights if they know hey are improperly managing someone else’s hardware. It's just the right thing to do if you ended up with someone else's registration in your console.

Next, if you really had to you would work with Apple and be clearer and more thorough and patient than the first time you asked for help. You will be seen as potentially someone looking to steal someone else’s hardware since Apple goes to pretty long lengths to validate a company before they allow DEP and the odds of mistakes that can’t be caught are low.

Worst thing - even if you accomplish your goal, I doubt you will ever be able to DEP that serial that was enrolled once and released. I’ve never heard of an exception to this. Maybe Apple would budge, but the warnings the releasing company sees before they release are quite dire and clear there is no going back once they rescind your/their one time DEP enrollment of a serialized product Apple sold to a validated business account.

You are likely going to have a long, hard  and unproductive experience with either a third party or Apple without specific documented proof a mistake was made. You might get what you want, but the desk is stacked against you accomplishing this for some really well considered reasons.

Comment: Great answer. Apple won't help you because what you're asking for opens the door to being able to steal devices...not that you're trying to do so, but they are leery of social engineering tactics.

Comment: The challenge is that I can't tell which organization has it in their DEP, just that *some* organization does. If it were enrolled in MDM then I would see that information, but DEP alone I don't.

Comment: @Matthew you can control the network the iPad uses and trace the url of their DEP server. You will know what server Apple has handed off your device to for control at that point.